# Multiple form buttons with AJAX, how to update form state storage data?

Tags: 8, forms, ajax

I have a form built with the Form API that has multiple `button` form elements. I don't want any of these to submit the form normally, I want them to utilize `#ajax` and callbacks to update the display. I feel like I run into this on every so often and can't quite remember how to make it work.

When the form first loads, I want half of the buttons to be `disabled`. When one of the buttons is clicked, I want to be able to detect this in `buildForm` so I can set form defaults and remove the `disable` property so other buttons can now be used.

I thought I could set storage in the callback and read it back the next time the form is built:

```
// Relevant bit of the form...
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-form-wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';

$form['actions']['update'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Start Form'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'my-form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'update'],
    'method' => 'replace',
  ]
];

$form['actions']['reset'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Reset Form'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'my-form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'reset'],
    'method' => 'replace',
  ],
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];

// The AJAX callback
public function update(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->set('flag_1', TRUE);
  $form_state->set('flag_2', "Started!");
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

The callback fires, and I see `$form_state` storage get updated with those arbitrary values, but when the form is rebuilt, I do not see them in `$form_state` anymore.

I looked at a few other similar form API AJAX questions, but did not have any luck getting unstuck.

Note: I do not want to have to juggle this with jQuery. I want to be able to update form data behind the scenes and rebuild the form appropriately with the relevant data.

Comment: with  #ajax you can also write #submit in form['actions']['update'] and then set the values over there. That should work. You don't want to do like that, is it ??

Comment: Say what? I don’t want to submit and reload the page, but I want to update the form state data with the press of any button. The data isn’t in the form the next time it is rebuilt

Comment: okay then do one thing....... $form['actions']['update'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Start Form'),
  '#submit' => ['::setAjaxSubmit'],                                                           
   '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'my-form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'update'],
  ]
]; In update just return the form field and in setAjaxSubmit method set the variable and rebuild the form

Comment: @ShreyaShetty, can you put the solution in an answer? This seems to be the the correct approach, but it's hard to read. Basically you build the form like a normal form and then ajaxify it by returning $form or the part inside of the ajax wrapper from the ajax callback to avoid a page reload. You can't change $form or $form_state from here and if the form logic works without ajax you don't need to, which is also advisable as fallback if javascript is not available.

Comment: @4k4 thank you for the wonderful explanation, will just put the solution in an answer

Comment: @Kevin I have the exact same problem. When I use the '#ajax' on a 'button' type values are not passed to the buildForm (like your example), but using the same '#ajax' on a 'textfield' the values are passed correctly to the buildForm. Did you ever figure this out?

Answer (score 2):

Please try this, as **@4k4** suggested you have to first build a normal form and ajaxify by using #ajax, and from the method defined inside #ajax you can return a $form and any fields inside the wrapper.

```
// Relevant bit of the form...
$form['#prefix'] = '<div id="my-form-wrapper">';
$form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

$form['actions']['#type'] = 'actions';

$form['actions']['update'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Start Form'),
  '#submit' => ['::setAjaxSubmit'],
  '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'my-form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'update'],
    'method' => 'replace',
  ]
];

$form['actions']['reset'] = [
  '#type' => 'button',
  '#value' => $this->t('Reset Form'),
  '#ajax' => [
    'wrapper' => 'my-form-wrapper',
    'callback' => [$this, 'reset'],
    'method' => 'replace',
  ],
  '#disabled' => TRUE,
];

// The AJAX callback
public function update($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
//return $form or part inside the ajax wrapper
return $form;
}

// The submit callback
public function setAjaxSubmit($form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form_state->set('flag_1', TRUE);
  $form_state->set('flag_2', "Started!");
  $form_state->setRebuild();
}
```

Comment: In this example, only one of those callbacks is ever called. Xdebug never triggers in the other callback.

Comment: You can try `'#executes_submit_callback' => TRUE,` or use `#type => 'submit'` where this is set as default, or move the code to form build where you check for the triggering element and only leave setRebuild() in the submit callback for a non ajax form submit.